# How to generate a HTML reports and send via email in SSRS Express

Tags: c#, sql-server, powershell, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Ok I know SSRS standard and enterprise has this feature built in, but I am using Express and there is no subscription option.

Is there a way for me to script this so I can generate the html report and email it via task scheduler? If I can generate the report which takes some parameters and output to a file, I will be able to script it.

Comment: Please, specify a more details. Do you want to be able to export the report from SSRS to html file?

Comment: Maybe this article below will help you?
https://kohera.be/blog/sql-server/emailing-ssrs-reports-on-a-scheduled-basis-without-using-subscriptions-or-attachments/

Answer (score -1):

Try to use: https://github.com/ps-monkey/PowerShell-Automation-Framework/
It has all you need to create a nice HTML report ans send it by email. Refer to an embeded doc for usage details.